# How to retain vertex names when combining graphs in iGraph?

Tags: r, union, igraph

I'm trying to combine to graphs with `graph.union` in iGraph, but when I do the resulting graph does not retain its vertex labels.

```
testGraph1 = barabasi.game(3, 
    m = 5,
    power = 0.6, 
    out.pref = TRUE,
    zero.appeal = 0.5,
    directed = TRUE)
V(testGraph1)$name = c('one', 'two', 'three')   

testGraph2 = barabasi.game(5, 
    m = 5,
    power = 0.6, 
    out.pref = TRUE,
    zero.appeal = 0.5,
    directed = TRUE)    
V(testGraph2)$name = c('one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five')   

combine = graph.union(testGraph1, testGraph2)
V(combine)$name #Is NULL
```

I also tried using `graph.union.by.name`, but I think there's a bug because both of the test graphs are definitely directed but I'm getting a weird error.

```
combine = graph.union.by.name(testGraph1, testGraph2)
#Error: !is.directed(g1) & !is.directed(g2) is not TRUE
```

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be a check at the start of graph.union.by.name that doesn't match up with the docs. If you remove that, and also add a directed option to the last line, I think you do get what you want:

```
gubm = function (g1, g2, dir=FALSE) 
{
  #stopifnot(!is.directed(g1) & !is.directed(g2))
    dv1 = igraph:::get.vertices.as.data.frame(g1)
    dv2 = igraph:::get.vertices.as.data.frame(g2)
    de1 = igraph:::get.edges.as.data.frame(g1)
    de2 = igraph:::get.edges.as.data.frame(g2)
    dv = igraph:::safer.merge(dv1, dv2, all = TRUE)
    de = igraph:::safer.merge(de1, de2, all = TRUE)
    g = igraph:::graph.data.frame(de, directed = dir, vertices = dv)
    return(g)
}

> combine=gubm(testGraph1,testGraph2,TRUE)
> V(combine)$name
[1] "one"   "three" "two"   "five"  "four"
```

But check this on plenty of examples to make sure it behaves properly. I suspect the igraph developers will spot this here, but you should report it as a bug on the [igraph mailing list](http://igraph.sourceforge.net) or in the [igraph bug tracker](https://bugs.launchpad.net/igraph).

I think the reason `graph.union` doesn't preserve the names is because there's no guarantee that all the graphs in the call will have the same attributes on their nodes, and its too much bother to check...

Comment: @ Spacedman: this is indeed a bug, I have no idea how this went unnoticed for a long time. Btw. https://bugs.launchpad.net/igraph is the best place to report bugs.

Comment: @Spacedman: That solution seems to work for me, although the graph size that `gubm` yields is different than what `graph.union` yields, so there's some inconsistency between those functions.

Comment: @erinshellman: what do you mean by graph size? Number of edges is of course different. Number of nodes can also be different, because `graph.union()` only uses the common nodes. In short `graph.union()` does not make much sense.... `gubm` does what you want I believe.

Comment: @Gabor Csardi: The number of nodes was different, so yeah, I'd agree that `graph.union` doesn't make much sense.